# Yoast XML Sitemaps on Wordpress NGINX server

Tags: wordpress, nginx, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I'm getting 404 error on my sitemap URL: https://www.smokebuddies.com.br/sitemap_index.xml

I've already put that all stuf on nginx.conf file:

```
> location ~ ([^/]*)sitemap(.*).x(m|s)l$ {
  rewrite ^/sitemap.xml$ /sitemap_index.xml permanent;
  rewrite ^/([a-z]+)?-?sitemap.xsl$ /index.php?yoast-sitemap-xsl=$1 last;
  rewrite ^/sitemap_index.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
  rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;
  rewrite ^/news-sitemap.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_news last;
  rewrite ^/locations.kml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_local_kml last;
  rewrite ^/geo-sitemap.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_local last;
  rewrite ^/video-sitemap.xsl$ /index.php?yoast-sitemap-xsl=video last;
}
```

But I'm still getting 404. Can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this works for me.

```
# Rewrites for Yoast SEO XML Sitemap
rewrite ^/sitemap_index.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;

#Yoast SEO Sitemaps
location ~ ([^/]*)sitemap(.*).x(m|s)l$ {
  ## this rewrites sitemap.xml to /sitemap_index.xml
  rewrite ^/sitemap.xml$ /sitemap_index.xml permanent;
  ## this makes the XML sitemaps work
  rewrite ^/([a-z]+)?-?sitemap.xsl$ /index.php?yoast-sitemap-xsl=$1 last;
  rewrite ^/sitemap_index.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
  rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;
  ## The following lines are optional for the premium extensions
  ## News SEO
  rewrite ^/news-sitemap.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_news last;
  ## Local SEO
  rewrite ^/locations.kml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_local_kml last;
  rewrite ^/geo-sitemap.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_local last;
  ## Video SEO
  rewrite ^/video-sitemap.xsl$ /index.php?yoast-sitemap-xsl=video last;
}
```

Comment: See https://yoast.com/help/xml-sitemaps-nginx/.